# How can I split a block of text into multiline records based on the starting line?

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, split

How can I split this into separate strings/arrays/etc so that I can then iterate on each one separately? The goal is to separate them so that I can then parse each record and insert into a PSCustomObject.

I have the following block of text representing more than 1 scan. Each scan record begins with 'Root Scan Path' line and ends with 'Suspicious Files' line.

The closest I have been able to get is the following line, which works but then I lose the 'Root Scan Path' line because it's the delimiter.

```
$String -Split "Root Scan Path: C:\\"
```

There could be more than 2 scan records as well.

```
Root Scan Path: C:\
Scan ID: 03307ad8-1a59-7d4e-8dfe-28864c9d1bc2
Status: Completed
Initiated from: User
Start Time: Monday, October 23, 2023 9:24:18 PM
End Time: Monday, October 23, 2023 9:34:00 PM
Scanned Files: 38311
Unsupported Files: 229479
Traversed Files: 321202
Total Files: 267790
Suspicious Files: 0
Root Scan Path: C:\
Scan ID: f32a64b0-56f5-664c-bf37-a7b120f759d8
Status: Running
Initiated from: User
Start Time: Tuesday, October 24, 2023 6:20:45 PM
End Time:
Scanned Files: 0
Unsupported Files: 0
Traversed Files: 0
Total Files: 0
Suspicious Files: 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming there are no empty rows between each block, the following might work:

```bash
$out = [ordered]@{}
$theInputString -split '\r?\n(?=Root Scan Path:)' | ForEach-Object {
    foreach ($line in $_ -split '\r?\n') {
        $key, $value = $line.Split(':', 2).Trim()
        $out[$key] = $value
    }
    [pscustomobject] $out
    $out.Clear()
}
```

I would recommend [Olaf's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77355469/15339544) using [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata?view=powershell-7.3) for its simplicity, however the cmdlet has a caveat that it doesn't preserve the order of the properties (because hashtables don't ensure its keys order),  <strike>also another caveat I have noticed is that it consumes the backslash `\` from the string (unsure if this is documented):</strike>

```bash
'Root Scan Path=C:\' | ConvertFrom-StringData
```

To clarify on the above, the backslash being consumed is expected as [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) points out in a comment, the character needs to be escaped with another backslash. See also [GitHub issue #20418](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20418).

```bash
'Root Scan Path=C:\\' | ConvertFrom-StringData

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Root Scan Path                 C:\
```

Comment: Very neat.   I actually missed that there are actually 2 data sets.  ‍♂️

Comment: Thanks @Olaf, your approach works well too, just needs a minor change, see here: https://i.imgur.com/Vk2zu0n.png // I'm not sure whats going on with this cmdlet consuming the ``\`` tho, thats pretty bad

Comment: I learned something useful from both of your answers so thx! I will accept this one since the core of the question was about splitting the block of text into its 2 separate sets of data. Your solution includes that in the first split. 

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I noticed the missing backslash when you mentioned it. ‍♂️ That wouldn't bother me but you're right - it's strange. Anyway I think your approach is more sophisticated and robust.  

Comment: From [`ConvertFrom-StringData`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-stringdata): "the cmdlet can interpret backslashes (``\``) as escape characters in the string data by using the `Regex.Unescape` Method". See also: [GitHub issue #20418](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/20418), which suggests an opt-out via a `-Raw` switch.

Answer (score 2):

I'd split on the line breaks and replace the first occurences of a colon with a unique character - an equal sign for example - and use `ConvertFrom-StringData` to get a proper PowerShell object.

```
@'
Root Scan Path: C:\
Scan ID: 03307ad8-1a59-7d4e-8dfe-28864c9d1bc2
Status: Completed
Initiated from: User
Start Time: Monday, October 23, 2023 9:24:18 PM
End Time: Monday, October 23, 2023 9:34:00 PM
Scanned Files: 38311
Unsupported Files: 229479
Traversed Files: 321202
Total Files: 267790
Suspicious Files: 0
Root Scan Path: C:\
Scan ID: f32a64b0-56f5-664c-bf37-a7b120f759d8
Status: Running
Initiated from: User
Start Time: Tuesday, October 24, 2023 6:20:45 PM
End Time:
Scanned Files: 0
Unsupported Files: 0
Traversed Files: 0
Total Files: 0
Suspicious Files: 0
'@ -split "\r?\n" |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_ -replace ':(?=\s|$)',' ='
    } | ConvertFrom-StringData -Delimiter '='
```

The output looks like this:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
Root Scan Path                 C:
Scan ID                        03307ad8-1a59-7d4e-8dfe-28864c9d1bc2
Status                         Completed
Initiated from                 User
Start Time                     Monday, October 23, 2023 9:24:18 PM
End Time                       Monday, October 23, 2023 9:34:00 PM
Scanned Files                  38311
Unsupported Files              229479
Traversed Files                321202
Total Files                    267790
Suspicious Files               0
Root Scan Path                 C:
Scan ID                        f32a64b0-56f5-664c-bf37-a7b120f759d8
Status                         Running
Initiated from                 User
Start Time                     Tuesday, October 24, 2023 6:20:45 PM
End Time
Scanned Files                  0
Unsupported Files              0
Traversed Files                0
Total Files                    0
Suspicious Files               0
```